# first last element 2nd variation

Tags: xml, xslt

XSLT XML Question.

I have another variation of my previous question. I have to output the the first and last page element of each section. AS shown below.

The XSLT 1.0 Solution and XSLT 2.0 Solution would be much appreciated. I thank you in advance for your time and help.

Thanks JJ.

Input:

```
<root>
  <page number="1" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="2" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="3" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="4" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="5" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="6" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="7" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="8" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="9" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="10" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="11" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="12" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="13" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="14" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="15" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="16" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="17" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="18" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="19" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
  <page number="20" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
  <page number="21" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
  <page number="22" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
  <page number="23" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
  <page number="24" section="ManCity">ManCity</page>
  <page number="25" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="26" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="27" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="28" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="29" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page>   
 </root>
```

Output:

```
 <root>
  <page number="1" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="6" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="7" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="12" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="13" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="18" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="19" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
  <page number="24" section="ManCity">ManCity</page>
  <page number="25" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="29" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
 </root>
```

Comment: Hello there. If you are going to refer to a previous question, you do at least need to actually provide a link to that question! Ideally, all questions should be self-contained though, to avoid the need to click through to other pages. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way, which will work in both XSLT1.0 and 2.0 is to simply have a template have will match **page** elements that have the same **@section** attribute as the most preceding and following siblings

```
<xsl:template match="page
    [@section = preceding-sibling::page[1]/@section]
    [@section = following-sibling::page[1]/@section]" />
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="page[@section = preceding-sibling::page[1]/@section][@section = following-sibling::page[1]/@section]" />

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the input XML, the following is output

```
<root>
   <page number="1" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page>
   <page number="6" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page>
   <page number="7" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page>
   <page number="12" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page>
   <page number="13" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page>
   <page number="18" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page>
   <page number="19" section="ManCity">ManCity</page>
   <page number="24" section="ManCity">ManCity</page>
   <page number="25" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page>
   <page number="29" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page>
</root>
```

In XSLT2.0 only though, you could make use of the **xsl:for-each-group** with the **group-adjacent** attribute.

This XSLT should also produce the same output

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:for-each-group select="page" group-adjacent="@section">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()[1]|current-group()[last()]"/>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```