# XSL for Xml to table transformation

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

Following up on my xslt question from yesterday, link found below.

[first last element 2nd variation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13116208/first-last-element-2nd-variation#comment17836389_13116208)

I have to output the the first and last page number of each section into a table.

I'm puzzled on where to start. The XSLT 1.0 Solution and XSLT 2.0 Solution would be much appreciated. I would really appreciate any given help.

Regards JJ.

INPUT:

```
<root>
  <page number="1" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="2" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="3" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="4" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="5" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="6" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="7" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="8" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="9" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="10" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="11" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="12" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="13" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="14" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="15" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="16" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="17" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="18" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="19" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
  <page number="20" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
  <page number="21" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
  <page number="22" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
  <page number="23" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
  <page number="24" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
 </root>
```

OUTPUT:

```
<tr><td>1</td><td>Arsenal</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>Chelsea</td><td>12</td></tr>
<tr><td>13</td><td>ManU</td><td>18</td></tr>
<tr><td>19</td><td>Mancity</td><td>24</td></tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="k" match="page" use="@section"/>

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <table>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="page[generate-id() = generate-id(key('k', @section))]"/>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="page">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@number"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('k', @section)[last()]/@number"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>Arsenal</td>
    <td>6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>7</td>
    <td>Chelsea</td>
    <td>12</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>13</td>
    <td>ManUnited</td>
    <td>18</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>19</td>
    <td>ManCity</td>
    <td>24</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Again Kirill Polishchuk. Your talent is much appreciated. Regards JJ.

Comment: how would the answer vary for XSLT 2.0?

Comment: @jay.james.666, Current solutions uses Muenchian Grouping. Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13115180/787016. It is easy to modify it to get desired result.

Comment: my solution does not seem to be working for XSLT 2.0. Shall I post an other question.

Comment: @jay.james.666, Sure. Post another one and specify that you are using XSLT 2.0.