# XSL for Xml to table transformation 2.0

Tags: html, xml, xslt

A follow up to previous question [XSL for Xml to table transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13131529/xsl-for-xml-to-table-transformation)
I have been working on XSLT 2.0 variation. I know I am doing something fundamentally wrong, but not sure what. Thanks in advance for the advice and guidance. Regards JJ.

Input:

```
<root>
  <page number="1" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="2" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="3" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="4" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="5" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="6" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page> 
  <page number="7" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="8" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="9" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="10" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="11" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="12" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page> 
  <page number="13" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="14" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="15" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="16" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="17" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="18" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page> 
  <page number="19" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
  <page number="20" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
  <page number="21" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
  <page number="22" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
  <page number="23" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
  <page number="24" section="ManCity">ManCity</page> 
 </root>
```

Desired Output

```
<tr><td>1</td><td>Arsenal</td><td>6</td></tr>
<tr><td>7</td><td>Chelsea</td><td>12</td></tr>
<tr><td>13</td><td>ManU</td><td>18</td></tr>
<tr><td>19</td><td>Mancity</td><td>24</td></tr>
```

Current XSL

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

  <xsl:template match="/root">
     <table>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="page" group-by="@section">
            <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@number"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:copy-of select="@section"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:copy-of select=".|current-group()[last()]"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Current Output

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td number="1"/>
        <td section="Arsenal"/>
        <td>
            <page number="1" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page>
            <page number="6" section="Arsenal">Arsenal</page>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td number="7"/>
        <td section="Chelsea"/>
        <td>
            <page number="7" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page>
            <page number="12" section="Chelsea">Chelsea</page>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td number="13"/>
        <td section="ManUnited"/>
        <td>
            <page number="13" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page>
            <page number="18" section="ManUnited">ManUnited</page>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td number="19"/>
        <td section="ManCity"/>
        <td>
            <page number="19" section="ManCity">ManCity</page>
            <page number="24" section="ManCity">ManCity</page>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your current output doesn't seem to have any relationship to your input. Tough to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks @Cheran Shunmugavel the output has been fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <table>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="page" group-by="@section">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@number"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@section"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[last()]/@number"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```